# Programmatically download SSH SFTP Certificate from Server (and save it)

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssh, ssh-keys

I'd like to make a function in a VB.NET app that allows the user to download the SSH\SFTP certificate from a server at the moment of the first log in, then save it into the user pc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

SSH doesn't use certificates, it uses SSH keys. When the SSH client connects to the server, the server's key is received from the server and passed for validation. Most SSH components on the market let you obtain this key, and then you can save the key and disconnect, if you don't need to proceed with connection.